# Make -j4 no longer compiles Device tree Binary for embedded

Tags: kernel, embedded

Until few days ago, I made some modification to my .dtsi file for embedded, in order to enable/disable I/O pins etc.
After to set environment variables, I wrote the command:

```
make -j4
```

and all .dtb files were ready to be used.
After to enter in menuconfig (but I didn't modify it), it no possible to obtain the updated .dtb files. The following is the logout when I launch `"make -j4"`:

```
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[1]: "include/generated/mach-types.h" è aggiornato.
  CHK     include/generated/bounds.h
  CHK     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  Kernel: arch/arm/boot/Image is ready
  Building modules, stage 2.
  Kernel: arch/arm/boot/zImage is ready
  MODPOST 21 modules
```

Possible solution?

Comment: Does no `-j4` make a difference?   Have you tried from a clean source tree?   Many makefiles don't really set up their dependencies correctly (leaving hidden race conditions) and parallel jobs can "randomly" fail and leave the source/output tree in a bad state.     Try cleaning your source tree and doing make without the `-j4`

Comment: Tried using a clean source tree. Same result.
I checked logout: found all .o file copied, some warning due to variables defined but not used, no errors detected. But NO .dtb files update after editing my .dtsi file.
What's missing?

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED!
Step-by-step procedure to build kernel from source code is the following:
1) set the environment variable:
source /opt/fslc-x11/2.2.1/environment-setup-armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi
2) clean all with:
make mrproper
3) set configuration:
make imx6ul-var-dart_defconfig
4) Customize the kernel configuration (if needed):
make menuconfig
5) Build what you need (in my case dtbs):
make -j4 dtbs

Well, in the previous procedure I forget step 3). Once all was done, Device Tree Blob built perfectly.
Just in case it 'd be useful for someone else.